# Error #1203: No default constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, events, constructor

i'm having a hard time understanding custom events and I keep getting this same error:
**1203: No default constructor found in base class flash.events:Event.**
I tried to read online for a solution, but nothing helped me. I was wondering what is my error. Basically, what I want to do is create a class that will, depending of the level of difficulty (3 in total), create different objects on the scene. Here's the code:

I call it with a dispatchEvent like so:

```
dispatchEvent(new creationObjets(_Difficulte));
```

then,

```
package cem{
    import flash.events.*;  
    import flash.display.*;

    public class creationObjets extends Event
    {
        public function creationObjets(pDifficulte) {
            trace(pDifficulte);
        }
    }

}
```

I have no idea what i'm not doing wrong (or just what I am doing, period... haha).
If you know the answer, maybe a little explication would help me a lot!
Thank you!

*edit: i just added super(pDifficulte); after the trace and no error came. I have no idea what super() does. I just did that based on examples...

Comment: Why are you importing flash.display.* classes?...

Comment: I was testing some stuff earlier, didn't remove it! hehe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
public class NewClass extends Event{
    public function NewClass(type:String) {
        super(type);
        trace("whatever");  
    }   
}
```

The `super()` method calls the constructor of the Event class. You should be familiar with it if you have some knowledge about OOP. The C# equivalent is `base()`

Comment: All right, thanks a lot! I think I understand better now. The problem is that i'm learning it at school, but we're skipping A LOT of basic informations. So I understand things that I'm not supposed to understand at this stage, but I'm not even aware of some basic stuff like that! haha. Anyway, I'm learning one (hundred) error(s) at a time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The code super() runs the method in the class you are extending. In this case it would run the constructor in the Event class.

Comment: Yess! Thanks for the answer! It was nowhere clear as those two lines everywhere I searched!